# modrewrite to another server if file/image is not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wampserver

Hi I am working on a locally served copy of a remote site and I don't want to have to download all the images rtelated to the site so I thought i could come up with a mod_rewrite rule for to grab images from the remote server if the are not found

I want to redirect  any image request that would result in a 404 to the remote server
ie something like this:

```
^localpath(.*) http://otherhost/localpath$1
```

this is the code that i have

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)) https://www.exmple.com/$1 [NC,P,L]
 </IfModule>
```

The page is still giving me 404's for images that are on the remote server, so this rule is not working.

I do know that the htaccess is being processed because rules later in the IfModule mod_rewrite.c block are being used.
(i simplified my code sample but this is the first rule in the IfModule mod_rewrite.c block)

**edit**
This code works to redirect all 404's

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.+) https://www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `!-f` in your `RewriteCond` so the rule applies to files which *don't* exist.

Also `$1` will be just the file extension because that group will get parsed first.  I think you want `$2`.

Files in subfolders don't start with / in the RewriteRule so you probably want to remove that from your match pattern as well.

Comment: My second suggestion comes courtesy of looking at this question, which may provide some additional perspective: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715069/mod-rewrite-number-of-parameters-back-references-limitation