# RewriteRule using $10, $11, $12, and so on

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, get

It seems that I cannot use a regex group when using mod rewrite, e.g.

```
results/(.*?)(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))(/(.*?))
```

That would do something like this:

```
results.php?a=$1&b=$3&c=$5&d=$7&e=$9&f=$11&g=$13&h=$15&i=$17&j=$19
```

For those numbers that have a `1` in it would append the `$1` group and a number, e.g.

`$1` is `a+typical+get+query`

and `$19` is the page number, it would return `a+typical+get+query9` as you can see the number is appended at the end.

`print_r($_GET):`

```
Array
(
    [a] => a typical get query
    [b] => some other field for the query
    [c] => 1
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 1
    [f] => a typical get query1
    [g] => a typical get query3
    [h] => a typical get query5
    [i] => a typical get query7
    [j] => a typical get query9
)
```

Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a limit of 9 back references ($1, $2,... $9) in mod_rewrite.

The $10 $11 etc back references are being interpreted as just $1.

See this post for some tips on conserving the back references (you'll have to write your rule differently):
[mod_rewrite number of parameters/back-references limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715069/mod-rewrite-number-of-parameters-back-references-limitation)