# htaccess rewrite get string to integer

Tags: .htaccess, get, url-rewriting

I want to receive a letter from a $_GET after making a post and rewriting an url with htaccess. For example:

```
$_POST['setting'] = 'w';
```

After a post I'm making a redirection like this:

```
/*more post variables here*/

$setting = $_POST['setting'];
header("Location{$basedir}page/$budget/$region/$reservations/$pool/$conference/$open/$meal/$setting/");
exit();
```

my htaccess configuration looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/[a-z]/?$ page.php?budget=$1.$2&region=$3.$4&reservations=$5&pool=$6&conference=$7&open=$8&meal=$9&setting=$10
```

I have tried with this too and had no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/?$ page.php?budget=$1.$2&region=$3.$4&reservations=$5&pool=$6&conference=$7&open=$8&meal=$9&setting=$10
```

After the redirection $_GET['setting'] is not a string as I expect but an integer.

```
URL example: server/site/page/0.0/0.0/0/1/1/0/0/w/
```

This is how a var_dump of $_GET looks like.

```
array (size=8)
 'budget' => string '15.30' (length=5)
 'region' => string '0.0' (length=3)
 'reservations' => string '0' (length=1)
 'pool' => string '1' (length=1)
 'conference' => string '0' (length=1)
 'open' => string '1' (length=1)
 'meal' => string '0' (length=1)
 'setting' => string '150' (length=3)
```

Any idea of what is going on here or what am I doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a limit of 9 back references in mod_rewrite, I read it from here [RewriteRule using $10, $11, $12, and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848962/rewriterule-using-10-11-12-and-so-on) so a solution could be add the next references in a variable as a string and use the php explode function to catch the results.

Answer (score 0):

try like that;

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/([0-9]+).([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ page.php?budget=$1.$2&region=$3.$4&reservations=$5&pool=$6&conference=$7&open=$8&meal=$9&setting=$1
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but still receive the same results from the var_dump n_nU, it is so weird :S

Comment: try my edited post and let me know what string you used for `settings` because you can only use `a-z`

Comment: I tried, for setting I used 'r', URL looks like this page/15.30/0.0/0/0/0/0/0/r/ I did an echo $_GET['r'] and the result was 15 this time.